# Add-WindowsFeature FS-NFS-Services "the name was not found"

Tags: powershell, network-shares, windows-server-2012, nfs

I have a fresh installation of Windows Server 2012 and need to create a NFS share.

Using [these instructions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574143.aspx):

```
PS C:\> Import-Module ServerManager
```

this works ok - I'm returned to the prompt.

```
PS C:\> Add-WindowsFeature FS-NFS-Services
```

*(EDIT: the line above is typed exactly as it appears on the MS documentation (last checked Feb 29, 2016)*

this returns the following error:

> Add-WindowsFeature : ArgumentNOtValid: The role, role service, or
>   feature name is not valid: 'FS-NFS-Services'.  The name was not found.

What is causing this and how do I resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft made a typo in their [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574143.aspx). It should be:

`Add-WindowsFeature FS-NFS-Service`

PS: dont forget to run PowerShell as `Administrator`.

[image]

Comment: `PS C:\> Add-WindowsFeature FS-NFS-Services` that is straight from [Microsoft's own documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574143.aspx).   Correcting their type-o worked.

Comment: Lol. I'll correct the answer!