# Where do I find PowerShell 5.1 modules that appear to be missing?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I've been trying to get an old NAS connected to my Windows 10 Pro laptop.

I enabled the NFS Client via `Programs and Features->Turn Windows features on or off`. For this reason, I can run `mount 192.168.x.x:/share Y:` successfully from `CMD`. This has problems with permissions, though, so I'm trying to figure out how to do it with PowerShell (v5.1) to see if that has options that allow me set permissions when I mount the share. Unfortunately, I don't have any of the NFS cmdlets. For instance, running `Get-NfsShare` throws the **unrecognized name** error:

```
The term 'Get-NfsShare' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again
```

Is there an official Microsoft repository from which modules can be installed? What would the NFS module even be called? It doesn't appear to be `NFS` or `nfs`.

**EDIT:** Powershell 5.1 (subject and body updated)

**EDIT 2:** I'm unable to even import the NFS module. It might be because I don't even know if I'm calling it by the correct name. If I am, then I'll definitely need to install something, eh?

```
> Import-Module NFS
The specified module 'NFS' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory
```

**EDIT 3:** I've been unable to install anything using `Add-WindowsFeature`. It appears that cmdlet is provided by the `servermanager` module which is not provided for Windows 10.

I also ran `Get-Module -list` to see which modules are available to me. Nothing indicates that any NFS modules exist. I also tried to run `Get-Command` to see which module might provide any of the commands I need, but even that came back as an unrecognized cmdlet, etc.

Comment: `PowerShell 5.1` or `PowerShell Core 6+`?  Please edit your question instead of replying with a comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell Invalid Spacename](https://superuser.com/questions/1444330/powershell-invalid-spacename)

Comment: @Ramhound I updated the question. The other that you linked to doesn't work. In fact, I'm getting the same error. :/ That said, I had already installed the NFS client via `Programs and Features->Turn Windows features on or off`.

Comment: The author of the duplicate accepted the answer as the solution.  So if you have the exact error as the duplicate, it seems to me, that the solution to the duplicate should have worked.  I assume you installed the feature as indicated by the answer?  **Have you imported the module within your script (`Import-Module NFS`)?**

Comment: As an Administrator run `Add-WindowsFeature FS-NFS-Service` with an elevated PowerShell command prompt and provide the results as a screenshot[,](https://superuser.com/questions/1045580/add-windowsfeature-fs-nfs-services-the-name-was-not-found)  You can always remove it if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ramhound It isn't the same error. Nowhere in the error that I'm getting does `Invalid spacename` appear. I've updated my question with further information regarding the `Import-Module` suggestion.

Comment: Have you ran both `Add-WindowsFeature` command and performed a reboot?  The author of the duplicate was getting both errors.  In my testing installing the feature should absolutely work.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm getting the same error that I was getting initially. Not getting the same error as the user in the other post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106124/discussion-between-ramhound-and-theillien).